# Winsock connect() error 10051

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winsock

I get an 10051 socket error every time I try to use this code:

```
    USES_CONVERSION;
LPTSTR addr = A2W("192.168.1.209");
m_pSMACLPRCli = new CSMACLPRCli(addr, 12010, m_hWnd);
m_pSMACLPRCli->StartThread();
```

This is the constructor for `m_pSMACLPRCli`:

```
CSMACLPRCli::CSMACLPRCli(LPTSTR lpsztIPAddress, int nPort, HWND hParentWnd)
```

And this is how I create the socket and connect:

```
void CBlockingSocket::Create(int nType /* = SOCK_STREAM */)
{
    ASSERT(m_hSocket == NULL);
    if ((m_hSocket = socket(AF_INET, nType, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
       TRACE("\n Socket Error !1 (%d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
       int err = WSAGetLastError();
}
}


BOOL CBlockingSocket::Connect(LPCSOCKADDR psa)
{
   ASSERT(m_hSocket != NULL);
   // should timeout by itself
   if (connect(m_hSocket, psa, sizeof(SOCKADDR)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
       int nLastErr = WSAGetLastError();
       return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```

The real funny thing is that when I use the exact same code, class structure etc. in a VS2008 project, everything works as expected, but when I use it in a VS2010 project, at `connect()` I get a 10051 error, `Network is unreachable`.

EDIT: The original VS2010 proj. is compiled using `UNICODE`. I've made a new VS2010 using `MULTI-BYTE` for testing and the `connect()` method returns no error, and ... connects. Could it be something wrong with my way of passing the address string to the constructor?

```
USES_CONVERSION;
LPTSTR addr = A2W("192.168.1.209");
m_pSMACLPRCli = new CSMACLPRCli(addr, 12010, m_hWnd);
m_pSMACLPRCli->StartThread();
```

SOLVED:

The real problem was not the `connect()` method, but had to do with my way of passing the address string to a constructor of a `sockaddr` object.

The constructor:

```
CSockAddr(const char *pchIP, const USHORT ushPort = 0) // dotted IP addr string
{
    sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin_port = htons(ushPort);
    sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(pchIP);
}
```

Constructor call used by me:

```
 CString m_strSrvIPAddr;    
 CSockAddr saServer((char *) LPTSTR(LPCTSTR(m_strSrvIPAddr)), USHORT(m_nPort));
```

I changed the call to this:

```
CStringA strAddr(m_strSrvIPAddr);
CSockAddr saServer((const char *) strAddr, USHORT(m_nPort));
```

So I had to do a conversion of the string from `UNICODE` to `MULTI_BYTE`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with code, I think. Try to ping this address.

Comment: I tried pinging, and there is no problem. I guess the problem comes from changing from VS2008 to VS2010, but why?, i have no idea.

Comment: Firewall or antivirus blocks VS2010

Comment: I've allowed VS2010 and any app. that i run from it through firewall and antivirus.

Comment: MRM, you should post your solution as an answer to your question, rather than add it to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `connect()`, you need to use `sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)` or `sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN6)` depending on what `psa` is actually pointing at. I would suggest having the caller pass in the actual size value:

```
BOOL CBlockingSocket::Connect(LPCSOCKADDR psa, int sasize)
{
   ASSERT(m_hSocket != INVALID_SOCKET);
   // should timeout by itself
   if (connect(m_hSocket, psa, sasize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
       int nLastErr = WSAGetLastError();
       return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}

SOCKADDR_IN sa;
...
Connect((LPSOCKADDR)&sa, sizeof(sa));
```

Alternatively, it would be better to use `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` and just type-cast it when passing it to `connect()`:

```
BOOL CBlockingSocket::Connect(const SOCKADDR_STORAGE *psa)
{
   ASSERT(m_hSocket != INVALID_SOCKET);
   // should timeout by itself
   if (connect(m_hSocket, (LPCSOCKADDR)psa, sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
       int nLastErr = WSAGetLastError();
       return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}

SOCKADDR_STORAGE sa;
...
Connect(&sa);
```

Comment: I managed to find the problem and fix it. It had to do with the address string and it's size, but not directly regarding the `connect()` method. The problem was in creating a `sockaddr`. Thanks for your help, the infos you provided led me to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this problem is not related to your code or the development environment but rather to the network the computer is connected to.

The output of ipconfig will let you know your IP address and the subnet mask which will allow you to understand which network you belong to.

The 192.186.0.0 network is a local address (behind a NAT) and you will not be able to connect to an address on this network unless you are part of it. If your IP address does not start with 192.168 it is the cause for the error you're getting.

Comment: I don't thing is the network, because, first i run the app. from VS2008 and it works, then i run it from VS2010, with the exact port and address as in 2008, and it can't connect.

Comment: I've updated my Question, please take a look. It's clear now that the network is not a problem, nor the code, but the way i wrote it for UNICODE. But i don't know what...